# Http request not working in Firebase webhook for google assistant

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, assistant

I have created the simple firebase function for Google assistant but when I try to send HTTP request I got an error in google actions simulator
`MalformedResponse
'final_response' must be set.`

The next action works properly:

```
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {
    conv.ask(`What do you want?`);
});
```

But the next is not working (produce the previous error):

```
app.intent('turnOff tv', (conv) => {
    request('http://someurl.com', (res) => {
        conv.ask('Alright, your value is');
    });
});
```

I was installing `request` module before (`npm install request --save`).
And I'm using the free firebase account.

How can I make an HTTP request in Firebase function while triggering a Google action from Google home?

Thanks!

Comment: All requests from the firebase webhook are blocked if u use the basic free plan. In other project plans it is working as needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, using the free plan for Google Functions, you cannot trigger a request for an external service other than Google.
The firebase **free plan** allows **outbound networking to Google Services only**.

Source: [Firebase pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) for details.